# LOG SHIPPING had to be made ACTIVE manually for applications to connect. How do we get back the missing transactions when PRIMARY went down

Tags: sql-server-2019

I am raising these on behalf of our DBA team. We are using **STANDARD EDITION of SQL SERVER 2019**. Let me explain with sequence of steps:

-> We have setup LOG SHIPPING (transactional backup happening every 15 mts). Say, 2:15pm, 2:30pm the transactional backup happens, and it is restored in LOG SHIPPING with no issues.

-> Before the next transactional backup happens at 2:45pm, ***the PRIMARY goes down (say, 2:40pm)***. So, there is about 10 minutes of transactions (2:40pm minus 2:30pm) that remains in PRIMARY but has not made it to LOG SHIPPING through transactional backup.

-> A situation arises where we make a decision to make LOG SHIPPING active manually using scripts and connect the application to this ACTIVE (originally LS database). Of course, there will be a downtime and we bring back the application say at 4.00pm.  The PRIMARY continues to be DOWN.

-> Customers (we somehow tell them that we will be able to restore the 10 mts missing data soon) continue to use applications say until EOD (10.00pm).  So, there is going to be new transactions in the original LS (from 4.00pm to 10.00pm).

-> At end of day, we were thinking, we will manually take the full back of LOG SHIPPING (that was made active) and try to RESTORE them in the PRIMARY (which say is back up by then).

**Here's the problem:** There is the 10 min of missing data (which was in primary that will be overwritten), data from 2:30pm to 2:40pm.

**Question:** Any way to retrieve that data that was originally in the primary when it went down?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is 10 minutes of data loss not acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response J.D.  There could be few financial transactions in this 10 minutes and it is difficult to convince the customers that their data is gone.  Again, the situation has not happened but we are planning our DR strategy.

Comment: Then your Transaction Log backups are not granular enough. You need to run them at a rate that is acceptable for data loss. If 5 minutes of data loss is ok, then run them every 5 minutes, otherwise if 1 minute of data loss is ok, then every 1 minute, etc. There are a multitude of scenarios that can go wrong and you'll lose data on unless you're taking backs more frequently than what's acceptable for data loss. I'm not super familiar with Log Shipping but I believe the scenario you described makes it impossible to restore the missing 10 minutes of data once users start writing to the database.

Comment: Thanks J D. Let me discuss this with the team

Comment: Np, best of luck!

Comment: @J.D. is correct - in the scenario you described, once you make that standby server active, then it effectively loses its reference to the transaction log backup chain from the "original" primary, so there is no way to isolate that 10 minutes worth of SQL transactions and somehow incorporate them into the "standby" (which has now started processing its own transactions).  So, yes, as J.D. also points out, it sounds like your log shipping intervals will need to be much shorter (but also with the proviso that there may still be a small amount of data loss)

Comment: The alternative is that you have a mechanism to identify all data records that have been inserted/updated/deleted during a period of time and can then script them from one database to another .... this can be very difficult, however, if you subsequently have the "standby" database become the "primary", as you will likely get new records in that primary with the same IDs/key field values as the "broken" primary.  Disaster recovery with a) minimal downtime, and b) absolutely no data loss at all is a complex thing, for sure

Comment: Remember that the process of getting the "original" primary back online will mean stopping system processing against the "standby" primary, backing up the "standby" primary's database and restoring it to the "original" primary, and then getting the transaction log shipping process going again (which involves another full backup from the reinstated primary to the "standby", and then the transaction log backups can start to flow again)

Comment: Thanks Craig, for your valuable input.  Now, the transactional backup is happening every 15 mts.  Just to minimize the data loss, as J.D mentioned, reducing that to 10mts or 5 mts will minimize data loss. But I was told, it might have an impact on the database performance (when there is high traction of users in our applications). Is that true?    Will the DB performance take a hit if we go to say 5 mts transactional backup intervals?

Comment: @ST "*Will the DB performance take a hit if we go to say 5 mts transactional backup intervals?*" - No one can say for sure without you trying it in your specific database under your specific workload, but typically that's not true. The reasoning being is the more frequently you back up the Transaction Log, the less data it needs to backup each time, so the faster that backup takes to complete. 15 minutes of Transaction Logs *may* be 3x as big as 5 minutes of Transaction Logs, and would then take roughly 3x as long to finish backing up. So increasing backup frequency means faster backups too.